# Java - How do I add up values in a file?

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array

I have a * delimited file containing counts from a log file by day.

I need to create an 'Overall Counts' file using this data however I cannot quite figure it out.

my file is laid out like this:

```
01/11/2014*0123*0*3*0*1
01/11/2014*4567*1*1*2*4
02/11/2014*0123*1*2*1*0
02/11/2014*4567*5*3*2*1
```

This is just a sample. However, the logic will be the same... I need to add up the values and get an output like this:

```
0123*1*5*1*1
4567*6*4*4*5
```

I'm currently iterating through the file line by line using a BufferedReader:

```
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) ...
```

In the file containing the daily data, the codes i'm interested in (0123, 4567) are always in the same position so I can either substring them:

```
String code = strLine.subString(11, 15);
```

or split the line on the *:

```
String[] line = strLine.split("\\*");
String code = line[1];
```

But here is where I get stuck... I need to go through the file looking for the 'code' and adding it to a count, what is the best way to achieve this? I tried with a 2D Array but couldnt quite get my head around it.

Comment: Do you just want to add up all the values after the first *, eg 0123, 4567 or do you want to save somehow them to process later?

Comment: the 0123, 4567 are codes which will be treated as the 'key' in the overall file.

Comment: A key for what? Can you specify your question a little? What do you mean by "I need to add up the values"?

Comment: To clarify, are you counting each unique instance of those two specific codes?

Comment: Does the result have to be in java? It is a two-liner in awk...

Comment: Yes, the 0123, 4567 may appear many times in the original file. I want to add up the four values that appear after that code throughout the original file and display the total in the output or "overall" file.

Comment: Use a `Map` where the key is the `String` "0123" or "4567" etc. And the Value is a 1D `int` array of size 4. As you're reading through the file, if your key is already in the map, then add each value to the array. If your key is not already present, create a new key and init a new value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
```

when iterating the file:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    int[] arr = map.get(key);
    //add values to array here
} else {
    int[] newValues = parsedValues;//can use String.split('*'); here from the substring of the line
    map.put(new String(key), newValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution that works. It may not be the most elegant, feel free to let me know if it can be improved.

```
public int[][] total(String fileName) {
    int[][] counts = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String strLine;
        Set<String> codeSet = new HashSet<String>();
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            codeSet.add(strLine.substring(11, 15));
        }
        String[] codes = codeSet.toArray(new String[codeSet.size()]);
        Arrays.sort(codes);
        counts = new int[codes.length][4];
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line = strLine.split("\\*");
        for(int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
            if(codes[i].equals(line[1])) {
                for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    counts[i][x] += Integer.parseInt(line[(x + 3)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
        br.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return counts;
}
```